# Proper database design and relationship for invoicing application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design, erd

I am creating an invoice application. Does the following flow diagram is the proper & complete application?

[image]

1. Am I missing any model?
2. Is there any other better way to design?
3. Is there any option to reduce the number of tables?
4. In the current model, when a user adds new invoice - I need to interact with almost all the tables.
5. When a user edits the same invoice - Again I need to interact with all the mentioned tables.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's hard to say, because only you know the specification of your application and what it should do and you are posting some **concept** not a **design** (eg. UML diagrams). But giving the information you provide:

1. Invoice have one contact. Would be better having issuer and contractor (two contacts) in case you want to issue an invoice from many clients.
2. I can answer that question when I see UML diagrams.
3. Why you want to reduce a number of tables? If you want to you can have one big table but that's not the point. Just keep your database desing normalized (3rd normal form) and don't care about number of tables.

On a must, I think you don't need tax and currency relations, you can move them to Invoice attributes - but once again, I don't have the whole picture.

4. No, you don't. When you issue a new invoice to the same customer and sell him the same items you just add records to two tables (invoices, invoice items). Anyway don't think about modyfing the database that way, you have the DB to work on it :)
5. As mentioned above - no.

Comment: Dear @justme, ignore 6th question. I have removed it. How an invoice can have 2 contacts. I have seen that scenario in real-time.

Comment: @Aravin I don't mean two contacts but "not only one issuer", eg. the company that issue an invoice can change in time.